# Hide action bar, but show when pulled down

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an action bar set up and it works great.  I'd like to have it so that it is hidden until the user does something like pull down from the top of the screen, and then show it.

I can't find any resources which discuss doing this.

Comment: Add a listener to your layout on a specific action (for example OnLongClickListener). When it is trigerred show you action bar

Comment: Great solution... not exactly what I had in mind, but works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Collapsing Toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="180dp"
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

       <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
           android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
               app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
       </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle its visiblity using OnClickListener on layout or if you have some layout that is scrolled by the user then you can experiment with OnScrollChangeListener.