# How to remove the Android notification bar/panel easily?

Tags: android, android-notifications, panel, android-notification-bar

I want to remove the Android notification bar/panel (in my original post I said service bar) at the top of the screen when you swipe down. I have read multiple questions but can't find the solution in an easy explanation. I want to use it for kiosk mode. Can someone help me out and explain where I have to add the code.

Thanks!

EDIT: I found this question on the website: [Disable the notification panel from being pulled down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920052/disable-the-notification-panel-from-being-pulled-down)
i want to know which code i can add and where in android studio.

Comment: There is no such thing as "android service bar", maybe you mean something else, please be more specific.

Comment: "explain where I add the code", which code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide action bar, but show when pulled down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433206/hide-action-bar-but-show-when-pulled-down)

Comment: Sorry i said it wrong. I want to stop the notification panel expanding if you swipe down.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the "ActionBar"?.

You can remove "ActionBar" by adding "android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" to the Activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml like below.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: This will remove the ActionBar permanently. The person who posted the question wants to remove it on swiping down

Comment: Sorry i mean the notification panel. Thank for your answer anyway!